# Assigning value from link table in a JPA ManyToMany Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm reasonably new to JPA mappings. I feel like this should be possible but I'm not sure how to do it.

I'm creating a ManyToMany mapping through a link table. This creates a list of SectorBean within a parent set. The link table contains a third unused column in the join. My question is if it's possible to store that column value as a transient variable in the SectorBean.

**SectorSetBean:**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "sectorassumptionlinks", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "set_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sectorid")
        )
@OrderBy(value="sector")
protected List<SectorBean> sectors = new ArrayList<>(0);
```

**Join Table:**
| set_id | assumptions_id | sectorid |
|:------|:----:| --------:|
| 567| 1891 | 333|

So in this instance the SectorSetBean uses the set_id and sectorid to create a List
And what I would like to have is something like:

**SectorBean:**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="sectors")
public class SectorBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    //In current example this would hold value 1891
    @Transient 
    Integer assumptionIdStoredAtRuntime;
}
```

I can't put the mapping I want (I don't think) into SectorBean because that doesn't have access to setId which is used to derive assumptions_id.

The setup of the beans and tables are legacy and I can't change the structure.

Does anyone know if this is possible or am I completely doing this wrong?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. `@Transient` attributes are ignored by JPA, that's the purpose of the annotation. You would need to introduce a new entity representing the join table (which is a common practice as join tables often get more attributes over time). If that's not possible, you might use a custom DAO query to retrieve the corresponding `assumption_id` explicitly.

Comment: You can look at map keys: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/MapKeyColumns which allow the relational table to store more data than just the relationship, but otherwise, you might want to make the relation table an entity in its own right for an SectorAssumptionLinks entity, with ManyToOne relationships to SectorBean. This would allow you to map and use the assumptionIdStoredAtRuntime where and when you might need it.